# create an array with a folder contents

Tags: node.js

I have a folder that contain some text documents,

I want to create an array that contain the names of the text documents.

the result must be like this:

array=[firstfile.txt],[secondfile.txt],[thirdfile.txt],ecc.

i know that i have to do something like this:

```
fs.readFile(foldername, function (err, content) {

var array = content.toString().split("...");
}
```

But i don't know what should I write in the `.split()`.

Some idea? thanks.

Comment: [`fs.readdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `fs.readdir` instead of `fs.readFile`.

`fs.readFile` is for getting the contents of a particular file, and the path parameter that you pass to it should be the path to a particular file, NOT to a folder.

`fs.readdir` is for getting the contents a particular folder/directory. Here the path parameter **should** be the path to a folder

The Node docs say:

> Reads the contents of a directory. The callback gets two arguments
>   (err, files) where **files is an array of the names of the files** in the
>   directory excluding '.' and '..'.

[Read more here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback). You'll have to see if the file names include the file extensions like you seem to want.